# display list value in template page using django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need to display the value of list in template page using django. I have a variable like

```
data = [('dic1',),('dic2',)]
```

I pass the value to the template this way:

```
 return render(request,'success.html',{'details':data})
```

Then in the template I need to show the value. I have used the for loop in the template like:

```
 {% for a in data %}
    {{a}}
 {% endfor %}
```

But it displays as

```
  ('dic1',)
  ('dic2',)
```

when I need to display only the value like below

```
   dic1
   dic2
```

Canyone help me to find out which mistake I did ?

Comment: You should try with 

`{% for a in details %}`
    `{{a}}`
`{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your response. I jus to use like below

```
 {% for a in data %}
     {{ a.0 }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Now it's working correctly.